# Using XFORM on PHONEGAP

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, xforms

I want to use xform on PhoneGap (not in Mozilla) but I couldn't find any tutorial,is anyone can help me that knows some tutorial or any experience with this two, I know this question is general but it doesn't matter the area or project.

just how can I use xform on phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use XForms on PhoneGap too!

Unfortunately, XForms is not natively supported by mobile browsers. So I tested my own XForms implementation (XSLTForms) which now works with Android.

The question for me is about XSLT being used within PhoneGap because XSLTForms is based on XSLT 1.0 to transform XForms into HTML+Javascript.

Do you have experimented XSLT in PhoneGap yet???

Thanks!

-Alain